# How does WorkManager's setRequiresDeviceIdle(true) work?

Tags: android, android-workmanager

I need to run a specific work only if the device is not in use. However, I don't fully understand how the `.setRequiresDeviceIdle()` constraint works.

I'm scheduling a worker like this:

```kotlin
val constraints = Constraints.Builder()
    .setRequiredNetworkType(NetworkType.CONNECTED)
    .setRequiresBatteryNotLow(true)
    .setRequiresStorageNotLow(true)
    .setRequiresDeviceIdle(true)
    .build()

val networkWorkRequest = PeriodicWorkRequestBuilder<NetworkWorker>(15, TimeUnit.MINUTES)
    .addTag(NetworkWorker.TAG)
    .setInitialDelay(15, TimeUnit.SECONDS)
    .setConstraints(constraints)
    .build()

WorkManager.getInstance(context)
    .enqueueUniquePeriodicWork(NetworkWorker.TAG, ExistingPeriodicWorkPolicy.REPLACE, networkWorkRequest)
```

Please note that the device is fully charged, has enough storage and an available internet connection at all times (meaning all first 3 constraints were met).

I've tried not touching the device for hours, closing all apps, even triggered doze mode (and then maintenance window) via ADB (with `adb shell dumpsys deviceidle force-idle` and then `adb shell dumpsys deviceidle step`), but nothing seems to work ([According to the docs](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/job/JobInfo.Builder?utm_campaign=adp_series_job_scheduler_092216&utm_source=medium&utm_medium=blog#setRequiresDeviceIdle(boolean)) this "idle" is not the same as doze mode, but I decided to give it a shot it anyway).

As you can see I've scheduled the job as periodic, just for the sake of checking if it would make any difference (in fact I only need a one-time worker). I left the device over night, and eventually the worker ran (these are some logs I'm writing to a file in the sd card):

```
1620688536155,2021.05.11 00:15:36.155,DEBUG,PRETTY_LOGGER,Enqueueing worker with id 931d2b1f-85f4-445f-a889-832fdd945752
1620712213970,2021.05.11 06:50:13.970,DEBUG,PRETTY_LOGGER,Running background work… --- job started running
1620712224898,2021.05.11 06:50:24.898,DEBUG,PRETTY_LOGGER,Response is: IT WORKS
1620712224899,2021.05.11 06:50:24.899,DEBUG,PRETTY_LOGGER,Done! --- job finished
```

I'm fine if my job runs at least once over night, because it's meant for triggering an update process, so I really need the device to be idle when it happens. In any case, I'd like to understand how to be sure that **it will run**, and how to mimic that for testing purposes (like we can do with doze mode, for example).

I've read a lot about it [in the docs](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/job/JobInfo.Builder?utm_campaign=adp_series_job_scheduler_092216&utm_source=medium&utm_medium=blog#setRequiresDeviceIdle(boolean)) ([WorkManager will use JobScheduler on API 23+](https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/architecture/workmanager), which is the case), [on Medium](https://medium.com/google-developers/scheduling-jobs-like-a-pro-with-jobscheduler-286ef8510129) (which says that "idle" is when the device "hasn’t been used in a little while") and went through a lot of SO questions, nobody seems to know how to properly test this.

Given the above, my questions are:

1. Can I force the device into a state where it is considered as "idle" by WorkManager to properly validate my work gets done?
2. Is there a good place to look for how/when WorkManager
   considers the device as being idle?

Comment: I think i found sth: https://aosp.opersys.com/xref/android-10.0.0_r36/xref/frameworks/base/services/core/java/com/android/server/job/controllers/idle/DeviceIdlenessTracker.java#68